# Kibana - intersection of two data sets

Tags: dictionary, location, kibana, intersection, geo

I have a index named 'request' with the below schema -

```
"id": "160c6273-8462-4830-9a51-dabf2e292ebb",
"username": "bob_dylan",
"date": "Jul 6, 2021 @ 12:00:00.000",
"location": {
    "lat": 48.8,
    "lon": 2.35
}
```

And my index properties are as below -

```
"mapping": {
    "properties": {
        "date": {
            "type": "date"
        },
        "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "username": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            },
            "fielddata": true
        }
    }
```

It is possible to choose 2 data sets with geo_bounding_box query and after it discover usernames that appears in both sets at least once?

P.S the same username can appear multiple times in the same set

[Kibana map choosing data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9gua.png)